# How to prove clickhouse 256 bits multiply right?

Tags: multiplication, biginteger, clickhouse

ClickHouse Use widen for 256bits interger, but its' multiply seems not strightforward.
https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/base/base/wide_integer_impl.h#L550

How to prove it rightness? I got confuse with that.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with perusing the referenced implementation in Abseil.

https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/absl/numeric/int128.h#L60

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).